# Form of elements in closed linear span

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and $\{x_j\}$ an orthonormal set in $H$. Let $C$ be the closed linear span of $\{x_j\}$.

I am trying to prove the following: Let $x$ be an element in $C$. Then $x=\sum a_jx_j$, where $a_j\in\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) such that $\sum|a_j|^2<\infty$.

---

My attempt is as follows. Since $C$ is $cl(span(\{x_j\}))$, there exists a sequence $(y_n)$ in $span(\{x_j\})$ converging to $x$.

Each $y_n$ is of the form $y_n=\sum a_{n_j}x_j$ where only finitely many $a_{n_j}$ are nonzero.

I am stuck at this step... Not sure if this approach is correct too.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Say $y_n$ is what you said, and $||x-y_n||\to0$. Let $$z_n=\sum_{j=1}^n a_jx_j,$$where $$a_j=\langle x,x_j\rangle.$$
Bessel's inequality, which presumably you've covered, says that $||x-z_n||\le||x-y_n||$.

**Details:**

**1.** Looking again at what you wrote, my $y_n$ is not exactly the same as yours.  You said $y_n=\sum a_{n_j}e_j$ where only finitely many coefficients are non-zero. Note first that you meant $\sum a_{n,j}e_j$, not what you wrote. And note that I'm assuming above that $y_n=\sum_{j=1}^na_{n,j}e_j$.

**2.** You ask how Bessel's inequality shows that $||x-z_n||\le||x-y_n||$. Where I come from this is exactly what Bessel's inequality *says*! In any case, here's why it's true:

You verify that $$\langle x-z_n,e_j\rangle=0,\quad(1\le j\le n).$$It follows that $$\langle x-z_n, z_n-y_n\rangle=0.$$Hence $$||x-y_n||^2=||(x-z_n)+(z_n-y_n)||^2=||x-z_n||^2+||z_n-y_n||^2\ge||x-z_n||^2.$$

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate a bit on how to use Bessel's inequality? When I tried using it I got $\sum|\langle x,x_j\rangle|^2\leq\|x\|^2$

Comment: @yoyostein See edit

Comment: @ David C.Ullrich: But how do you have $||x\to y_n||\to 0$? I can't see why this is trivial from definition of the closed linear span.