# $\overline{\text{span}[S]}=H$ iff $S^{\perp}=\{0\}$

Tags: functional-analysis

I need to prove: If $S$ is a subset of a Hilbert space $H$, then the closed linear span of $S$ is all of $H$ iff $S^{\perp}=\{0\}$.

I'm confused how to characterize an element in $\overline{\text{span}[S]}$. Some [links](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629281/form-of-elements-in-closed-linear-span) works for an orthonormal set, but the argument doesn't work in case of an arbitrary set $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the theorem that if $V$ is a closed linear subspace of the Hilbert
space $H$ then $H=V\oplus V^\perp$. Apply to $V=\overline{\text{Span}(S)}$.
Then $V=H$ iff $V^\perp=0$, But $V^\perp=S^\perp$.

Comment: Could you please explain further why $V^{\perp}=0\Rightarrow V=H$ and $V^{\perp}=S^{\perp}$?

Comment: If a vector is orthogonal to all elements of $S$, it is orthogonal to all elements of the span of $S$ and so then to all elements of the closure of the span of $S$. @George_K